# Qt training tips and tricks

Tags: qt

I have just arrived at new company and have never worked with Qt before, but my task is to learn Qt in 2 weeks, so i can give training to others. So i got 2 weeks to learn Qt and prepare for 2 weeks long Qt teaching.
I am so dead!
Please point out some common mistakes, tricks, styles so i can make that training a bit better!

Thank you!

EDIT:
I used this book - C++  GUI Programming with Qt 4 and it was very good. Examples were really good. Also I had some training materials from previos training. That was 2 week traning and we covered almost all Qt aspects! Nice one! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get [C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160), (the official Qt book) and start reading!

Answer (score 2):

At first you should understand the [signal/slots concept](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html), because that is used heavily in Qt. Then I would work through some simple examples, there are lots of them, so just pick the ones you like. If you use Qt Creator you have the context sensitive documentation always at hand, which helps a lot.

If you think you know the basics you can concentrate on the more complicated things like threading or network communication, depending on what your company focus is.

Remember the Qt is not only the GUI framework, but has a framework for a lot of lowlevel components, too. Have a look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/overviews.html) to get an overview.

Comment: signals/slots - done!
One question - when i connect on signal to another and second signal to slot and triger first signal - who will be sender(), when slot receives signal?

Comment: Not sure. I'd say it has to be the original sender, because the 2nd sender only serves as "proxy" and is not actually emitting the signal. Have a look at qDebug(), it can print almost anything on stdout so you can compare pointers in this case if you want to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872494)
2. [Examples and Demos Launcher](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtdemo.html)

Doing all advises from that links, will gave you the right direction to move.

PS: I think 2 weeks not the problem to start using Qt...

Answer (score 1):

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/tutorials.html is the well known QT tutorial found in the web. You can also try this book [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Prentice-Source-Software-Development/dp/0132354160](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160).

Answer (score 1):

If you already know C++, start developing Qt applications using Qt. You can use the 
examples, Qt- Assistant and also [Qt classes for 4.6](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/classes.html) site. IMHO, only by **practicing** you can learn Qt nicely. Read the books and links specified in the answers and **start creating applications**. Start with the simple one and move forward towards the complex. 2 weeks is quite enough time to learn Qt.

Answer (score 1):

If learning by yourself in teaching doesn't cut it (quite ambitious if it is supposed to be more than first steps and an overview), you could attend a Qt training, offered by Nokia/Qt partners such as KDAB and ICS.